# What is the best way to determine an intersection between 2D shapes on a cartesian grid?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, graphics, geometry

The function below is supposed to determine whether two objects of the movingBall struct are "touching" with each other

```
 bool areBallstouching(movingBall one, movingBall two)
{
    int xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax;
    int TxMin, TxMax, TyMin, TyMax;
    xMin = one.xPosition - one.radius;
    xMax = one.xPosition + one.radius;
    yMin = one.yPosition - one.radius;
    yMax = one.yPosition + one.radius;
    //===================================
    TxMin = two.xPosition - two.radius;
    TxMax = two.xPosition + two.radius;
    TyMin = two.yPosition - two.radius;
    TyMax = two.yPosition + two.radius;
    //=======================================

    vector <int> xrange, yrange, Txrange, Tyrange;
    bool xtouch = false; bool ytouch = false;
    for (int i = xMin; i < xMax; i++)
    {
        xrange.push_back(i);
    }
    for (int i = yMin; i < yMax; i++)
    {
        yrange.push_back(i);
    }
    for (int i = TxMin; i < TxMax; i++)
    {
        Txrange.push_back(i);
    }
    for (int i = TyMin; i < TyMax; i++)
    {
        Tyrange.push_back(i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < xrange.size(); i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < Txrange.size(); j++)
            if (xrange[i] == Txrange[j])
                xtouch = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < yrange.size()-1; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < Tyrange.size()-1; j++)
            if (yrange[i] == Tyrange[j])
                ytouch = true;
    if (xtouch == true && ytouch == true)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I reasoned that the balls can only be touching each other if they share any two coordinates. If they share only an x-coordinate, they will be aligned vertically but the bottom point of the topmost ball will not contact the top point of the bottom-most ball. If they share only a y-coordinate, they will be aligned horizontally but the right-most point of the left-most ball will not touch the left-most point of the right-most ball.
[image]

The attached picture demonstrates this reasoning. When I implemented the code, I did not achieve the results I wanted. The program was not able to properly detect the intersections between the two circles.

Comment: This is an exceptionally complicated way of testing whether two circles are touching.  Why not just test the distance between their centres is less than or equal to r1 + r2?  Or better, the distance squared is less than or equal to r1*r1 + r2*r2...  so you don't need to calculate any square roots.

Comment: Correction: `sq(dist) <= sq(r1 + r2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathematically, the point where two circles touch will separate their center positions by a distance equal to the sum of the two radii.  It follows:

- if distance between centers is less than the sum of radii, circles intersect;
- if distance between centers is greater than the sum of radii, circles do not intersect (or touch).

So, all you need is a simple distance calculation with basic Pythagoras.

```
float dx = two.xPosition - one.xPosition;
float dy = two.yPosition - one.yPosition;
float distsq = dx * dx + dy * dy;   // square distance between centers
float r = one.radius + two.radius;  // sum of radii
float rsq = r * r;

bool intersect_or_touch = (distsq <= rsq);
```

Note that above we can operate in the domain of square distance and square radii to avoid needing to use a `sqrt` calculation.

Comment: Note that I've used `float` in the calculations, but since all your values are apparently integers _and_ we don't need to do square roots, then all the math will work with integers too, provided you do not overflow the integer's valid range.

Comment: hello paddy, thanks for your response. I have an additional question to ask if you don't mind.
this is the equation that I got for calculating the x overlap:
cos(tan^-1(two.yPosition - one.yPosition/two.xPosition-one.xPosition))*((dy^2+dx^2)/2)-(one.radius+two.radius/2). 
Is this correct?

Comment: Best to ask a new question, both for a broader reach (instead of me being your personal tutor) and clarity (using formatting and providing extra detail not possible in the limits of a comment).  When you do ask this question, I suggest you define exactly what "x overlap" means.  To me, that means the _two_ x-positions at which two circles intersect (or _one_ if they exactly touch).  You could do this with Pythagoras, or vector math, or by solving quadratic.  To answer _your_ equation, why don't you actually try it and devise tests and/or a mathematical proof.

Comment: Oh, I'll also add that when you ask that question, say what you actually wish to achieve with it.  Notice how the answer you got for this question isn't at all how you were trying to solve the problem.  It might be the same with your current thinking.  For instance, if you're trying to compute a bounce direction after a circle collision, the proper thing to do is use vector math, not trigonometry.